# Pegar o valor de um input em JS para enviar para arquivo PHP

Tags: php, javascript, webcam

tenho um script de webcam dentro de um formulario e preciso que quando eu tire a foto, ele salve o arquivo com o nome digitado na input no mesmo formulario.

Essa é a parte do código da webcam onde ele manda para um arquivo php salvar a foto

```
var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function() {      
    $.post('library/salvar.php?nome='.nome, {imagem:canvas.toDataURL()}, function(data){
    },'json');
});
```

Arquivo PHP que recebe a foto e salva

```
function base64_to_jpeg( $base64_string, $output_file ) {
    $ifp = fopen( $output_file, "wb" ); 
    fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $base64_string) ); 
    fclose( $ifp ); 
    return( $output_file ); 
}       
$imagem = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,','',$_POST['imagem']);        
base64_to_jpeg($imagem, "../assets/fotos/".$_GET['nome'].".png");        
echo json_encode(array('imagem' => 1));
```

Porém ele não ta salvando, acredito que nesse trecho eu esteja fazendo errado:

```
'library/salvar.php?nome='.nome,
```

Por favor me ajudem!!!

RESOLVIDO!
Substitui a linha

```
$.post('library/salvar.php?nome='.nome, {imagem:canvas.toDataURL()}, function(data){
```

Por

```
$.post('library/salvar.php?nome='+$("input[name=nome]").val(), {imagem:canvas.toDataURL()}, function(data){
```

Comment: Para concatenar strings no javascript, é necessário utilizar o sinal **+** ao invés do ponto. `$.post('library/salvar.php?nome='+nome`

Comment: Muito bem lembrado amigo @ValdeirPsr, porém agora ele salva a foto só que sem nome..

Comment: Resolvido amigo... fiucou assim $.post('library/salvar.php?nome='+$("input[name=nome]").val()  e consegui salvar com o nome! obrigado meu amigo!